# Combining lines that are tab delimited

Tags: bash, macos, sorting, combiners

I've got all the lines in a proteins_num sorted numerically, I now need to combine the lines with identical number in a way so that new information is added to the upper line:

When I've sorted all the lines numerically, I need to combinde the lines with identical number in a way so that new information is added to the upper line. Take for instance the lines with no 61:

: Col | : 1 | : 2 | : 3 | : 4 | : 5 | : 6 | :7 | : 8 | : 9 | : 10 | : 11
: ----| : 61| :PTS... cyt 1bl.. 0,38 MONOMER homo-trimer FRUC... PER...Bac.. 
      61 PTS...                                                         3

becomes:

Col    1  2      3   4      5     6        7         8      9     10   11 
      61 PTS... cyt 1bl.. 0,38 MONOMER homo-trimer FRUC... PER...Bac..  3

Sometimes there'll be information missing in some columns in the upper line that is found in the lower one. Therefore the order of joining must be concise.

Is If there are info in both lines that doable?

The file is here with 1021 lines

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yuu46crp7ql4z65/Proteins_num.txt?dl=0

Comment: This should be easy with Awk. What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I've looked at this :http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193748/join-lines-of-text-with-repeated-beginning but being new to programming it seems really complicated, and I don't need to combine it just after each other, because the order of information need to be in the right column (I'll just clarify above in an edit).

Comment: Also, what happens when you have two different values in column 2 for same value in column 1?

Comment: Then [edit] your question to update it with the *precise* code you used and the *precise* error you get.

Comment: Also, if you are new to programming, it would be best to focus on a smaller piece of the puzzle. We will be happy to teach you more Awk, but very reluctant to do your actual work for you (especially if you don't seem to care about learning).

Comment: I tried to edit my question. I'm thinking that I need to figure out first, how to make awk know which lines to joing (not all numbers have two lines). I'm thinking that it's something like       awk BEGIN or awk NUM to make sure it chooses from the first column, but I don't know how to specify that the numbers should match. Is this the right way to start?

Comment: `awk -F$'\t' 'BEGIN{c=0;}{b[$1]++;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i)a[$1","i]=$i} if(c<NF)c=NF;}END{for(j in b)for(i=1;i<c;i++)printf "%s\t", a[j","i];print a[j","c]}' protein.txt` This would do; but I am sure there should be a duplicate question for this. Plus, this solution does not take care of the case I mentioned in my previous comment. So, not adding it as answer.

Comment: I can't get the awk to work, and neither the editing of columns... Can you guys suggest a way for me to start learning more efficiently from scratch? An online course or so? Then I can use this forum more effciently for help with other stuff than weird things from my PhD project. I feel a bit lousy just asking all the time and not understanding the long answers...

Answer (score 0):

An awk/gawk solution could be:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN { SEQ="" }; 
  $1 == SEQ { $1=""; printf("%s\t",$0)}; 
  $1 != SEQ { SEQ=$1;  printf("\n%s",$0);}
' Proteins_num.txt
```

where SEQ is the number at beginning of line. When it detects a numeration change, print last line with carriage return. If no change is detected, line is printed without break line, to join with next line. File must be numerical sorted previously.